# what is directive for millisecond? like %f is for microsecond

Tags: python, numpy

%f is for microsecond but timestamp that I have is 2020-05-21 13:05:30.683
(683 is in millisecond). I need it as millisecond only. But am not aware of which directive to use instead of %f that's for microsecond.

```
purchase, sold, timestamp = np.loadtxt("BalData.txt", delimiter="|", unpack=True,
                                             converters={2: mdates.datestr2num('%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S.%f')})
```

'''
I tried

```
purchase, sold, timestamp = np.loadtxt("BalData.txt", delimiter="|", unpack=True,
                                         converters={2: datetime.isoformat(sep=' ',timespec='milliseconds')})
```

but i got an error(Exception: descriptor 'isoformat' of 'datetime.datetime' object needs an argument)

Comment: Please always include tags for libraries like `numpy` and `pandas` if they are relevant to your question.

Comment: time is in this format in file 2017-01-01 13:25:55.683

Comment: `%f` assumes trailing zeros; a time like `13:05:30.683` is parsed the same as `13:05:30.683000`.

Comment: @chepner you are right but have to keep millisecond as millisecond only.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you want, as neither `matplotlib.dates.datestr2num` (I'm assuming that's what you are referring to) nor `datetime.isoformat` are used in the way you are showing. The former takes a date string, not a format, and the latter is an instance method.

Comment: Perhaps `converters={2: lambda d: d.isoformat(sep=' ', timespec='milliseconds')}`?

Comment: @chepner you are right i have not used the correct type for I was initially using 'matplotlib.dates' datestr2num('%Y-%M-%D %H:%M:%S.%f') but it won't work for it's deprecated. secondly file has millisecond not microsecond.